# Can a powerline reduce the internet connection speed of other devices?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, speed, powerline-networking

"It seems" that my powerline adapter reduces the speed of other devices; I think is just a coincidence cause I was lagging one our ago and the test on http://speedtest.net was ok (so I think it gave me a bad result).

So is the powerline limiting the download speed (12mbps to 4mbps) ?

Comment: Is the computer you are testing connected through powerline and is the powerline connection slower than your internet connection?

Comment: Most Powerline adapters have a utility that they come with, or is available from the manufacturers website, that can report the link quality and bandwidth available. If not, these protocols are very generic, the Netgear utility I had would see all brands of devices. I would suggest starting there and making the link is clean and not inducing noise (in this case, flooding the network with packets) into the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

If other devices are cabled in and do not connect through it, then a power line would not slow the network down, but devices connecting to the power line might.

It is possible that the power line device is emitting RFI and interfering with WIFI, but this should not be the case - they operate on different frequencies.

It is possible that there is another Ethernet path between devices connected to the powerline and this is causing issues - but this would be equally true if it were an Ethernet cable.

The powerline device might be acting as a router, or have a built in wifi AP ( powerline is a technology (as @grawity pointed out often using the Home plug standard) and many types if devices use it) - but  issues relating to devices using it would not typically be attributable to powerline if the data does traverse it.

I surmise that if your incoming broadband runs parellel and close to your house power wiring it could induce crosstalk and reduce your Internet speeds.  Power and network should not be until very close together though - so it would be a house wiring issue.

In general - tyou can use tools like (Win) MTR and watch latencies and see where packet loss comes in. It can help pinpoint where problems are occurring and could help rule it out as a possibility.

Comment: Powerline by itself is not a standard; G.hn and HomePlug (AV) are standards. Most powerline devices use HomePlug AV.